# UniQuery - How to find the largest length of a field in a file

Tags: u2, unidata, uniquery

I'm trying to figure out how to find the largest length of records for a field in a file on a Unix-based Unidata database in a Manage2000 (M2k) MRP system.  I currently have the "Using Uniquery" and "Uniquery Command Reference" both for v7.2 and the closest that I have found is using "LIKE" and "UNLIKE", but it isn't working exactly like I was hoping.

Basically, we have an QUOTES file with a "Part_Nbr" dictionary and I need to find the length of the largest "Part_Nbr" record in the file.  The dictionary field maximum length is 19 characters.  In doing a random listing of records, I see some records have data length of 7 characters and some have 13 characters, but I need to find the largest data length.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Best Regards,

--Ken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I will clarify some terms so that we are speaking the same language. You are appear to be using field and record interchangeably.

A **FILE** (aka TABLE for SQL folk, 'QUOTES' in this case) contains 0 or more **RECORDS**. Each record is made up of multiple **ATTRIBUTES** (aka FIELD). You can reference these attributes using dictionary items (which can also create derived fields)

In this case you want to find the longest length of data accessed via the Part_Nbr dictionary, correct?

Assuming this is correct, you can do it as follows

## Use a dictionary Item

**Step 1:** Create a I-type dictionary item (derived field). Let us call it Part_Nbr_Len. You can do this at the command line using `UNIENTRY DICT QUOTES Part_Nbr_Len` as per the image below.

[image]

- Type = **I** (aka Derived Field)
- LOC = **LEN(Part_Nbr)** (The field is the number of 1 byte characters in the Part_Nbr field)
- FORMAT = **5R** (Right-aligned makes it treat this field as a number for sorting purposes)
- SM = **S** (This field is a single value)

**Step 2:** List the file in descending order by Part_Nbr_Len and optionally as I have done, also list the actual Part_Nbr field. You do this by the following command.

`LIST QUOTES BY.DSND Part_Nbr_Len Part_Nbr_Len Part_Nbr`

[image]

---

## Temporary command-line hack

Alternatively, if you don't want something permanent, you could do a bit of a hack at the command line:

`list QUOTES BY.DSND EVAL "10000+LEN(Part_Nbr)"  EVAL "LEN(Part_Nbr)" Part_Nbr`

[image]

Okay, let's break it down:

- `list` -> May or may not be important that this is lowercase. This enables you to use 'EVAL' regardless of your account flavor.
- `EVAL` -> Make a derived field on the fly
- `10000+LEN(Part_Nbr)` -> Sorting of derived field is done by ASCII order. This means 9 would be listed before 15 when sorting by descending order. The + 10000 is a hack that means ASCII order will be the same as numeric order for numbers between 0 and 9999 which should cover the possible range in your case
- `EVAL "LEN(Part_Nbr)"` -> Display the actual field length for you.

---

**EDIT**

## Solve via code for MultiValued lists

If you have a MultiValued (and/or Sub-MultiValued) attribute, you will be required to use a subroutine to determine the length of the largest individual item. Fortunately, you can have a I-type dictionary item call a subroutine.

The first step will be to write, compile and catalog a simple UniBASIC subroutine to do the processing for you:

```
SUBROUTINE SR.MV.MAXLEN(OUT.MAX.LEN, IN.DATA)

* OUT.MAX.LEN  : Returns the length of the longest MV/SMV value
* IN.ATTRIBUTE : The multivalued list to process

  OUT.MAX.LEN = 0
  IN.DATA = IN.DATA<1> ;* Sanity Check. Ensure only one attribute
  IF NOT(LEN(IN.DATA)) THEN RETURN ;* No Data to check

  LOOP
    REMOVE ELEMENT FROM IN.DATA SETTING DELIM
    IF LEN(ELEMENT) > OUT.MAX.LEN THEN OUT.MAX.LEN = LEN(ELEMENT)
  WHILE DELIM
  REPEAT

RETURN
```

To compile a program it must be in a DIR type file. As an example, if you have the code in the 'BP' file, you can compile it with this command:

`BASIC BP SR.MV.MAXLEN`

How you catalog it depends upon your needs. Their are 3 methods:

- DIRECT
- LOCAL -> My suggestion if you only want it in the current account
- GLOBAL -> My suggestion if you want it to work across all accounts

If you have the program compiled in the 'BP' file, the catalog commands for the above would be:

- `CATALOG BP SR.MV.MAXLEN DIRECT`
- `CATALOG BP SR.MV.MAXLEN LOCAL`
- `CATALOG BP SR.MV.MAXLEN`

After the subroutine has been cataloged, you will need to have the `LOC` field (attribute 2) of the dictionary item Part_Nbr_Len (as per first part of this answer) updated to call the subroutine and pass it the field to process:

`SUBR("SR.MV.MAXLEN", Part_Nbr)`

Which gives you:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your response.  Fantastic answer!  I'm still fairly new at working with Unidata and Uniquery, so my lingo is definitely off.  Your alternative method for finding the length is the method that I would use, since nothing permanent is needed.  Unfortunately, I didn't realize the "Part_Nbr" dictionary is multi-valued, so if multiple parts are entered for the quote, the length could be very long, with all of the P/N considered in the length check.  Is it possible to consider each P/N individually in the MV dictionary for an individual length check?  Best Regards, Ken

Comment: Thanks @Ken. I've updated it with a third section to address you question. It is slightly more complex though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fantastic answer.  With more recent versions of Unidata there's a slightly easier, more efficient way to check for the longest MV field though.

If the DICT item becomes:

```
SUBR('-LENS', Part_Nbr);SUBR('SR.MV.MAXLEN',@1)
```

The basic program can become simpler and just find the MAXIMUM value of the multivalued list of lengths:

```
SUBROUTINE SR.MV.MAXLEN(OUT.MAX.LEN, IN.DATA)
    OUT.MAX.LEN=MAXIMUM(IN.DATA)
RETURN
```

Too bad there's no '-MAXIMUMS' built in function to skip the basic program entirely!  It's worth reading section 5.9 of the UniQuery docs at:

[Rocket Software Uniquery Docs](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/products/unidata/resources/manuals/unidata-7.2-documentation/udtu-v7r2.pdf)